# Scattering cross section for distinguishable particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, scattering-cross-section

I am reading Quantum Mechanics book by N. Zettili (2nd ed.) and encountered something confusing in the chapter of scattering theory, section 11.5: scattering of identical particles.

This is the problem:

First it is mentioned that for two classical identical particles, whose interaction potential is central the differential scattering cross section is given by (in center of mass frame),

$$ (d \sigma (\theta)/d \Omega )_{cl} = |f(\theta)|^2 +  |f(\pi - \theta)|^2 $$

Here $f(\theta)$ is the scattering amplitude, which appears in the scattered wave function.
Then after a few lines it is mentioned that for distinguishable particles when $ \theta = \pi/2 $, the differential cross section is $ |f(\pi/2)|^2 $.

I think classical identical particles are always distinguishable. So, it should be $ 2 |f(\pi/2)|^2 $, not  $ |f(\pi/2)|^2 $, according to the 1st formula.

What am I missing here ?

Comment: *"I think classical identical particles are always distinguishable."* Why? If you have two identical classical particles and you shoot both of them into a box where they scatter off each other and then one of them comes out of the box at a certain angle, how are you going to tell "which one of them" it was?

Comment: @ACuriousMind I might be wrong, but I always thought that classical particle means a macroscopic particle. So even if they look identical, they might have some other character to distinguish them. Like some molecules of a gas, they are identical but they might have some internal modes such as vibrations and rotations etc, which we can use to distinguish them.

Comment: @ACuriousMind In your experiment, suppose we have two baseballs and we put two different radioactive substances inside them, then they may look identical but they will radiate different particles. So we can distinguish them. I think classical identical particles means, they just look identical but internally they may differ. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: What is $f$?  How is it defined?  There does appear to be an inconsistency given what you've described, but without more context it's impossible to say what it might be (or if it actually exists.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Yeah, I have mentioned it now.

Comment: How is $f$ a scattering amplitude for a *wavefunction* (a quantum mechanical concept!) when this expression is supposed to be for "classical identical particles"?

Comment: @ACuriousMind Are you suggesting Quantum Mechanics can't be applied to classical particles ? As far as I know the concepts can be applied to macroscopic as well as to microscopic particles

Comment: "Classical", to me, is a synonym for "not-quantum mechanical" (and sometimes for "non-relativistic"). If you apply quantum mechanics to "classical particles", you're no longer dealing with "classical particles", you're dealing with quantum objects, regardless of size. You can't simultaneously claim something is classical and then apply non-classical (i.e. quantum) thinking to it.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Does that mean what's written in Zettili's book is wrong?

Comment: @ACuriousMind I have posted an answer. What do you think about it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think I have figured it out now. For two distinguishable particles the formula for differential scattering cross section will be (in center of mass frame),

$$( d \sigma (\theta)/d \Omega)_{distinguishable} = \frac{1}{4}(|f_1 (\theta)|^2 + |f_2 (\pi - \theta)|^2 + |f_2 (\theta)|^2 + |f_1 (\pi - \theta)|^2). $$

It's kind of obvious and the factor $1/4$ appears because all 4 possibilities are equally probable. So, when $\theta = \pi/2$,

$$ ( d \sigma (\theta)/d \Omega)_{distinguishable} = \frac{1}{4}(2|f_1 (\pi/2)|^2 + 2 |f_2 (\pi/2)|^2 ).$$

Now if the particles are identical, then $f_1 = f_2 = f $. Therefore the differential cross section would be $|f(\pi/2)|^2.$

Comment: Books referred: Quantum Mechanics by N. Zettili

Comment: J J Sakurai modern quantum mechanics was helpful too.